# Adding file to existing zipfile

Tags: python, zip, python-zipfile

I'm using python's `zipfile` module.
Having a zip file located in a path of:
`/home/user/a/b/c/test.zip`
And having another file created under `/home/user/a/b/c/1.txt`
I want to add this file to existing zip, I did:

```
zip = zipfile.ZipFile('/home/user/a/b/c/test.zip','a')
zip.write('/home/user/a/b/c/1.txt')
zip.close()`
```

And got all the subfolders appears in path when unzipping the file, how do I just enter the zip file without path's subfolders?

I tried also :
`zip.write(os.path.basename('/home/user/a/b/c/1.txt'))`
And got an error that file doesn't exist, although it does.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You got very close:

```
zip.write(path_to_file, os.path.basename(path_to_file))
```

should do the trick for you.

Explanation: The `zip.write` function accepts a second argument (the arcname) which is the filename to be stored in the zip archive, see the documentation for [zipfile](https://docs.python.org/2/library/zipfile.html) more details.

`os.path.basename()` strips off the directories in the path for you, so that the file will be stored in the archive under just it's name.

Note that if you only `zip.write(os.path.basename(path_to_file))` it will look for the file in the current directory where it (as the error says) does not exist.

Answer (score 38):

```
import zipfile

# Open a zip file at the given filepath. If it doesn't exist, create one.
# If the directory does not exist, it fails with FileNotFoundError
filepath = "/home/user/a/b/c/test.zip"
with zipfile.ZipFile(filepath, "a", compression=zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED) as zipf:
    # Add a file located at the source_path to the destination within the zip
    # file. It will overwrite existing files if the names collide, but it
    # will give a warning
    source_path = '/home/user/a/b/c/1.txt'
    destination = 'foobar.txt'
    zipf.write(source_path, destination)
```

**WARNING**: [The `ZipFile` class has a compression parameter](https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/zipfile.html#zipfile-objects). By default it is `ZIP_STORED` (no compression)! If you want compression, set `compression=zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED`.

Comment: I would give you more upvotes if I could. Furthermore, this needs to be the accepted answer because of completeness.

Comment: please note, this example does not include any compression. before you copy\paste please read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4166447/python-zipfile-module-doesnt-seem-to-be-compressing-my-files