# Trying to zip some files in python. But the size is not getting compressed.

Tags: python, python-3.x, shell, unix, zip

I am trying to zip some files present in a directory. Zipping is done successfully, but size doesn't seem to compress a lot.

My code :

```
import os
import zipfile
import sys
def zipdir(client, path):
    os.chdir(path)
    if client == 'ABC':
        zipf = zipfile.ZipFile('Store.zip', 'w')
        zipf.write('Facts.txt')
        for f in os.listdir(path):
            if f.endswith('.txt') or f.endswith('.xls'):
                if 'pretty' in f:
                    zipf.write(f)
        zipf.close()
```

When I try to zip it in unix shell script, the size becomes 40M. 
But When I try to zip it in Python, size is 196M

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Possible duplicate: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4166447/python-zipfile-module-doesnt-seem-to-be-compressing-my-files

Comment: You just have to supply the compression parameter ZIP_STORED or ZIP_DEFLATED. https://docs.python.org/2/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python zipfile module doesn't seem to be compressing my files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4166447/python-zipfile-module-doesnt-seem-to-be-compressing-my-files)

Comment: Thanks everybody. That helped. Seems like i could have searched some more ;)

Answer (score 4):

You have to specify the compression when making the `zipfile.ZipFile`

## ZipFile constructor

> class zipfile.ZipFile(file, mode='r', compression=ZIP_STORED,
>   allowZip64=True)

[ZIP_STORED](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZIP_STORED) is uncompressed:

> The numeric constant for an uncompressed archive member.

so you will have to change that to one of these

> compression is the ZIP compression method to use when writing the
>   archive, and should be ZIP_STORED, ZIP_DEFLATED, ZIP_BZIP2 or
>   ZIP_LZMA;

## Context manager

And it's better to work with a context manager (`with`) which automatically opens and closes the file, also when something goes wrong

so you can change that portion to something like

```
with zipfile.ZipFile('Store.zip', 'w', compression=zipfile.ZIP_LZMA) as zipf
    zipf.write('Facts.txt')
    for f in os.listdir(path):
        if f.endswith('.txt') or f.endswith('.xls'):
            if 'pretty' in f:
                zipf.write(f)
```

depending on the chosen compression algorithm